# Cluster formation on single machine, starting second node crashes because port in use

Tags: rabbitmq

On my desktop I'm trying to create a RabbitMQ cluster. After installing RabbitMQ server v3.7.14 (and Erlang v21.3), the first `rabbit@localhost` node is installed on port `15672`. I'm trying to set up a second node by following this documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine.

To create a second node with name `hare@localhost`, I execute the following commands on CMD:

```
set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
set RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}]"
set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=hare@localhost
rabbitmq-server.bat
```

But `rabbitmq-server.bat` causes a crash and following is logged:

```
[error] <0.509.0> Failed to start Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672 in ranch_tcp:listen([{cacerts,'...'},{key,'...'},{cert,'...'},{port,15672}]) for reason eaddrinuse (address already in use)
[error] <0.509.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.509.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {listen_error,rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672,eaddrinuse} in ranch_acceptors_sup:listen_error/5 line 66
[error] <0.507.0> Supervisor {<0.507.0>,ranch_listener_sup} had child ranch_acceptors_sup started with ranch_acceptors_sup:start_link(rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672, ranch_tcp) at undefined exit with reason {listen_error,rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672,eaddrinuse} in context start_error
[error] <0.449.0> ** Generic server rabbit_web_dispatch_registry terminating
```

Do I have to do the same for `Ranch listener` as what I did for `rabbitmq_management` as above (setting it to port 15673, to avoid conflicts)? But I don't know how I have to set `RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS` for the `Ranch listener`...

Can anyone help me with configuring `RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS` for the `Ranch listener`?

**EDIT**

Here is the crash dump:

```
Error description:
    init:do_boot/3 line 823
    init:start_em/1 line 1115
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 480
    rabbit:broker_start/0 line 356
    rabbit:start_apps/2 line 575
    app_utils:manage_applications/6 line 126
    lists:foldl/3 line 1263
    rabbit:'-handle_app_error/1-fun-0-'/3 line 696
throw:{could_not_start,rabbitmq_management,
       {rabbitmq_management,
        {bad_return,
         {{rabbit_mgmt_app,start,[normal,[]]},
          {'EXIT',
           {{could_not_start_listener,
             [{port,15672}],
             {shutdown,
              {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
               {listen_error,rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672,eaddrinuse}}}},
...
```

Comment: Don't put double quotes around the value for `RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS`. Windows quoting rules are different than POSIX shells.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: Sorry, we installed the nodes on separate servers. I didn't look into this anymore.